# Objective-C/iOS: Get date for specific day in week (sunday)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I need to get the date of a specific day (Sunday) in the current week. I use this date to determine if some weekly resetting should occur, and I do some calculations on last reset date is before sundays date etc. This has in principal been ask and answered many times, and my solution has worked for the past 6 months. But today, the 29th of December 2013, it stopped working.

The function used at present time:

```
+ (NSDate *) getSundaysDate{
    NSDate *currentDate  = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setFirstWeekday:1];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit)  fromDate:currentDate];

    NSDateComponents *dt = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [dt setWeek:[components week]];
    [dt setWeekday:1];
    [dt setMonth:[components month]];
    [dt setYear:[components year]];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:dt];
}
```

This used to work like a charm, but today, on my apps, this returns:

```
NSLog(@"sundaysDate %@", [Util getSundaysDate]);
sundaysDate 2012-12-29 23:00:00 +0000
NSLog(@"Current date %@", [[NSDate date] debugDescription]);
Current date 2013-12-29 11:37:23 +0000
```

Notice the 2012.

I know this has been answered several times, in different contexts, so I apologize in advance, but I simply don't get the 2012.

**Edit - just to clarify the functionality needed:**

Week starts on Sunday(day 1)

Week ends on Saturday(day 7)

Given current date I need the date of the first day of the week.

```
Example 1: today is 29th December 2013
Expected: Sunday is 29th December 2013

Example 2: today is 4th January 2014
Expected: Sunday was 29th December 2013

Example 2: today is 8th January 2014
Expected: Sunday was 5th January 2014
```

Comment: No repro here. What system are you running on?

Comment: Danish localization, Testing simulator on Mavericks and iPhone5 iOS 7. Same result here on both simulator and iPhone. I'm guessing it has to do with the first week (week 1) in 2013 is actually in 2012.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this. German locale, Xcode 5.0.2 on Mav in iOS 7 Sim. Guess we have a Bug Report for Apple

Comment: Tried setting up a test device running iOS 6 to English local, using United states as region format, same result.

Comment: Can you also log the `currentDate`?

Comment: Of course, current date added after SundaysDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `WeekOfMonth` not `Week`.
`NSWeekCalendarUnit` is essentially week of year so specifying both it and month are in conflict.

Note that `NSWeekCalendarUnit` is obsolete:

> **Deprecation Statement**
>   Use `weekOfYear` or `weekOfMonth` instead, depending on what you intend.

```
NSDate *currentDate  = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setFirstWeekday:1];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit)  fromDate:currentDate];
[components setWeekday:1];

NSDate *sundatsData = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"sundaysDate: %@", sundatsData);
```

NSLog output:

> sundaysDate: 2013-12-29 05:00:00 +0000

Comment: On my system that yields "2013-11-30 23:00:00 +0000", expected date is "2013-12-29 23:00:00 +0000".

Comment: Opps, there was a typo, Should be: `[dt setWeekOfMonth:[components weekOfMonth]]; `, fixed.

Comment: [dt setWeekOfMonth:[components weekOfMonth]]; - perfect. This looks much better. Let me test throughly and update.